# MBA 2017 won't boot up in macOS, but will in Ubuntu

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

A few days ago my spouse's MBA started showing problems. At first it wouldn't turn on at all, showing an orange indicator on the MagSafe charger. After resetting the SMC a couple times and letting it charge for a long time it booted up.

It showed the regular login screen but it wouldn't complete the login, it'd just sit on the end of the progress bar.

I tried booted in recovery mode, single mode, internet recovery mode, and afterwards a freshly made USB macOS Mojave installer I made on my MacBook Pro 2018.

None of the above complete the boot up. Instead, it sits forever on the 100% progress bar. I started the Mojave installer in verbose mode and I see an "Unsupported CPU" and "Unsupported PCH" in the log.

[image: screenshot]

I was able to boot up a live Ubuntu USB and everything seems ok. I installed the Ubuntu on the main disk to see if there was a problem with the disk at all. Ubuntu runs just fine on the MBA.

Any ideas on what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

While the "Unsupported CPU" and "Unsupported PCH" messages in the log appear concerning, I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that this is what's causing the problem. The fact is I've seen these messages before in Macs that run perfectly fine.

I see you've already reset the SMC, but you haven't mentioned resetting the NVRAM and this is something you should also do.

**Reset your NVRAM**

For your model MBA you'll need to follow these steps:

1. **Fully shut down your MBA**
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again (i.e. wait until you've heard the startup chime a second time)
4. Let go of the keys and let your MBA reboot.

It's not clear to me if you still have macOS installed or not:

- **If not**, then shut down your Mac again and switch it on and immediately press the <kbd>option</kbd> key and let me know what drive options (if any) appear on the screen.
- **If so**, what happens when your MBA boots up after the NVRAM reset?